# Converting tile image into raster using rasterio

Tags: python, raster, rasterio, aerial-photography

I want to convert a tile image (.tif) into a raster data (.tif) and assign lon/lat to the data. (I know how to get the lon/lat of a tile.)

The problem is I don't know how to assign lon/lat to a raster image. The only method I know is copy the format of a raster image to another. But the location of the tile will be totally wrong.

The library I use is rasterio on Python. Here's the code I've tried

```
import numpy as np
import rasterio
import rasterio.features
import rasterio.warp
from affine import Affine

# copy the format of this raster image
with rasterio.open('SN5_roads_train_AOI_7_Moscow_PS-RGB_chip999.tif') as src:
    transform = src.transform
    #transform = Affine.identity()
    crs = src.meta['crs']
    mask = src.dataset_mask()
    print(rasterio.features.shapes(mask, transform=src.transform))
    # Extract feature shapes and values from the array.
    for geom, val in rasterio.features.shapes(mask, transform=src.transform):
        # Transform shapes from the dataset's own coordinate
        # reference system to CRS84 (EPSG:4326).
        geom = rasterio.warp.transform_geom(
            src.crs, 'EPSG:4326', geom, precision=6)

# read the rgb of the tile image
with rasterio.open('original.tif') as src:
    r, g, b = src.read()
    print("bounds")
    print(src.bounds)
    print("meta")
    print(src.meta)

# generate the raster image
with rasterio.open(
    'generated_raster.tif',
    'w',
    driver='GTiff',
    height=r.shape[0],
    width=r.shape[1],
    count=3,
    dtype=r.dtype,
    crs=crs,
    transform=transform,
    #transform=Affine.identity(),
) as src2:
    src2.write(r, 1)
    src2.write(g, 2)
    src2.write(b, 3)
    print("new.tif meta")
    print(src2.meta)

with rasterio.open('generated_raster.tif') as src:
    transform = src.transform
    crs = src.meta['crs']

    mask = src.dataset_mask()
    print(rasterio.features.shapes(mask, transform=src.transform))
```

I am new to GIS and raster data.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. This is such a common task I don't want to believe there is no simple straightforward solution for this.